# Performace queries regarding inner_hits for nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Below are the specification about my index:

1. Around 600-700 million documents
2. _source is **disabled**
3. For each field in index **store=true** is marked.
4. ES version **7.10.2**

When a search is performed on the document instead of returning all the fields/or whole document, User can ask for a specific field(for which store is marked as true).

But the nested fields are not returned as part of stored field, as mentioned in ES doc.

> On its own, stored_fields cannot be used to load fields in nested
> objects — if a field contains a nested object in its path, then no
> data will be returned for that stored field. To access nested fields,
> stored_fields must be used within an inner_hits block.

Query:

```
POST order/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "009"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "OrderStatus",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            "inner_hits": {
            "stored_fields" : ["OrderStatus.Status"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But my main concern is what is the performance cost of making such nested inner hits queries:

- As of each hit, an nested inner hit query will be made, if my search result hits 20 million records, for each of those 20 million, it will make an inner hit query, will it not degrade the performance?

I have gone through # of articles for the same, but most of them are for the older versions, here is one of the discussion:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14229

Can anyone please help me with this?